# Rubber-band graph embedding under gravity

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Let $G$ be a simple $3$-connected plane graph with the vertices of
its outer face pinned to the $xy$-plane.
View each edge as an ideal rubber band, and each internal
node given a weight proportional to its vertex-degree.
The weights pull down the nodes vertically under gravity,
so that the network sags into the halfspace $z \le 0$.

So this is a
[Tutte embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_embedding)
with the addition of degree-weights
pulling in the $-z$ direction.
For example, here is the graph of a cube:

---

[image]

---

This is not so interesting because the four internal nodes
each have the same degree, $3$.
Here is an example where $u_1$ has degree-$3$
and $u_2$ has degree-$4$.
Despite $u_2$'s heavier weight, $u_1$ is slightly lower
in equilibrium.

---

[image]

---

Two questions:

> ***Q1***. Has this degree-weighted representation been studied
> before? If so, does it possess any "nice" properties?

> ***Q2***. (This is too much to hope for, but...)
> Is every node of $G$ on the convex hull of the network in equilibrium?

I expect the answer to ***Q2*** to be *No* because one can
arrange, say, a high-degree node surrounded by low-degree nodes.
But the balance of the rubber band forces complicates matters,
as hinted in the example with a lighter node below a heavier node.